# How to introduce string by keyboard in child after fork

Tags: c, concurrency, process, signals, scanf

I'm exercising over concurrency in C, I wrote a small and simple program in which a parent process creates two children, sender and receiver.
Sender will read from stdin a string and then procede to send it in some way to receiver (not relevant).

The real problem here is that when I run the program, it executes the fork, the two children will be born, sender is supposed to wait a string as input, BUT I can't find a way to insert anything using terminal.
The program seems like to hangs over the scanf, but I cannot find a way to introduce any input. The terminal, once the program has started, just doesn't let me insert anything.

I'm using Xcode 6.3.2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define FILE_NAME "conteggio"
#define MAX_CHAR 25

void receiver();
void sender();

void receiver_operation();
void sender_operation();
void to_maiusc(char s[], char* r);
int readline(int fd, char *str);
void nothing() {}

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} boolean;
int sender_pid, receiver_pid;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE *f_in;
    int status, num, sender_pid, receiver_pid;
    // create the two childs
    if ( (sender_pid = fork()) != 0 ) {
        // I'm the father
        if ( (receiver_pid = fork()) != 0 ) {
            // wait until the two processes return
            wait(&status);
            wait(&status);
            // read the number of interactions
            if ( (f_in = fopen(FILE_NAME, "rb")) != NULL ) {
                fread(&num, sizeof(int), 1, f_in);
                printf("Il numero di interazioni è: %d", num);
                fclose(f_in);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            // Sono il receiver
            receiver_operation();
        }
    }
    else {
        // sono il sender
        sender_operation();
    }
}

int readline(int fd, char *str) {
    char c = '\0';
    int i = 0;
    while (c != '\n') {
        read(fd, &c, 1);
        str[i] = c; i++;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void sender_operation() {
    FILE *fin;
    int r_pid, count = 0;
    char stringa[MAX_CHAR+1];
    boolean finito = FALSE;
    signal(SIGUSR1, nothing);

    // aspetto che il receiver scriva sul file il pid e lo apro
    pause();
    if ( (fin = fopen("pid", "rb")) == NULL ) {
        printf("Impossibile aprire file 'pid'.\n");
        return;
    }

    // leggo il pid
    fread(&r_pid, sizeof(int), 1, fin);
    fclose(fin);

    while (!finito) {
        // leggo una stringa da tastiera
        kill(0, SIGSTOP);
        printf("Insert a string: ");
        scanf("%s", stringa);

        // controllo se è 'end'
        if ( strcmp(stringa, "end") == 0 ) {
            finito = TRUE;
        }

        // scrivo su file
        if ( (fin = fopen("stringa.txt", "w")) == NULL ) {
            printf("Impossibile aprire file 'stringa.txt'.\n");
        }
        fprintf(fin, "%s", stringa);
        fclose(fin);

        // segnalo al receiver che il file e' pronto
        kill(r_pid, SIGUSR1);

        // aspetto il risultato
        pause();

        // leggo il risultato
        if ( (fin = fopen("stringa.txt", "r")) == NULL ) {
            printf("Impossibile aprire file 'stringa.txt'.\n");
            return;
        }
        fscanf(fin, "%s", stringa);

        // stampo il risultato
        printf("Stringa processata: %s", stringa);
        fclose(fin);

        // incremento numero iterazioni
        count++;
    }

    // stampo su un file il numero di iterazioni
    if ( (fin = fopen(FILE_NAME, "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Impossibile creare il file %s\n", FILE_NAME);
        return;
    }
    fwrite(&count, sizeof(int), 1, fin);
    fclose(fin);
    exit(0);
}

void receiver_operation() {
    FILE *fout;
    int pid;
    boolean finito = FALSE;
    char stringa[MAX_CHAR+1], result[MAX_CHAR+1];

    signal(SIGUSR1, nothing);

    // scrivo il mio pid su un file
    if ( (fout = fopen("pid", "wb")) == NULL ) {
        printf("Impossibile creare il file 'pid'\n");
        return;
    }
    pid = getpid();
    fwrite(&pid, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
    fclose(fout);

    // segnalo il file pronto
    kill(sender_pid, SIGUSR1);

    while (!finito) {
        // ora aspetto che il sender scriva una stringa sul file 'stringa.txt'
        pause();

        // leggo la stringa da processare
        if ( (fout = fopen("stringa.txt", "r")) == NULL ) {
            printf("Impossibile aprire il file 'stringa.txt'\n");
            return;
        }
        fscanf(fout, "%s", stringa);
        fclose(fout);

        if ( strcmp(stringa, "end") == 0 ) {
            finito = TRUE;
        }

        // processo la stringa
        to_maiusc(stringa, result);

        // scrivo sul file il risultato
        if ( (fout = fopen("stringa.txt", "w")) == NULL ) {
            printf("Impossibile scrivere il risultato su 'stringa.txt'\n");
            return;
        }
        fprintf(fout, "%s", result);
        fclose(fout);

        // segnalo il risultato pronto
        kill(sender_pid, SIGUSR1);
    }
}

void to_maiusc(char s[], char* r) {
    int i;
    r = malloc( sizeof(char) * strlen(s) +1);
    // converto la stringa da maiuscola a minuscola
    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++) {
        r[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Anybody has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I got it right, your problem is that child process is failing to read `stdin`, right? You may use `fscanf(stdin, stringa);`

I've tested with a simple example and worked (just changing your **scanf** by **fscanf**). Let me know if that was your problem.

Comment: I'm so happy to say "You are right".
That solved my problem.
Anyone knows why using scanf brings problems here?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this may concern file descriptors. When your child process uses scanf, it tries to read standard input which is the pipe. Thus, it's necessary to specify stdin to avoid such behavior. But again, I'm just guessing.